# PHP was compiled with zlib module, but phpinfo() show it's disabled

Tags: linux, php, source-code, module

In order to use Joomla! 4.3.1, I've compiled PHP 8.2 in an Oracle Linux 8.6 Server, with support for zlib compression:

```
# php --ri zlib

zlib

ZLib Support => enabled
Stream Wrapper => compress.zlib://
Stream Filter => zlib.inflate, zlib.deflate
Compiled Version => 1.2.11
Linked Version => 1.2.11

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
zlib.output_compression => On => On
zlib.output_compression_level => -1 => -1
zlib.output_handler => no value => no value
```

```
# php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
(...)
zip
zlib
```

And I've enabled `zlib.output_compression = On` on `/etc/php.ini`, which is the configuration file being used by PHP:

```
# php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

Nonetheway, `phpinfo();` still shows that gzip compression is disabled:
[image: phpinfo() output]

Does someone have any hint on why PHP is having such behavior?

Note: I've compile with the following parameters:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --disable-rpath --disable-debug --enable-calendar --enable-sysvshm  --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-ctype --enable-exif --enable-ftp --with-gettext --enable-mbstring --enable-shmop --enable-sockets --with-zlib=/usr --without-pgsql --disable-static --with-layout=GNU --with-curl=/usr --with-mhash=/usr --with-unixODBC=/usr --with-snmp=shared --enable-soap --enable-sysvsem --enable-sysvshm --enable-pcntl --enable-mbregex --with-zip --with-pdo-mysql --with-mysqli --with-openssl --enable-fpm --with-kerberos --with-xsl --enable-opcache --enable-intl --with-pear --with-oci8=instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/21/client64/lib --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phar zlib support isn't the same as zlib support within PHP. That's all there is too it - phar is a code archive format, and it not having enabled zlib compression support is not an indication of zlib in other parts of PHP not working.

PHP error hints and documentation being misleading is not a new thing! In this case you've been led astray by the "install ext/zlib"; that is probably a separate extension and not the zlib support of PHP itself.

Friendly remark on your efforts: I'd refrain from building PHP from scratch. If recommend that you either

- start a podman container with a distro inside that has a well-maintained and security-updated PHP 8.2 itself
- or backport the PHP 8.2 rpm from such a distro to your CentOS.

Since PHP 8.2 is still very young (do you *really* need it? The newest bleeding edge software is not necessarily optimal for server applications! Joomla's website says any PHP 8.x is good enough, so you could just use the well-packaged 8.0.27 for your distro and have zero of the trouble and well-tested software), that choice of distro is probably going to be fedora 38 (it's currently not packaged for CentOS stream 9/rhel9/alma9).

The container setup would be boringly simple, a Dockerfile containing naught but

```
FROM fedora:38

RUN dnf install --refresh -y php-fpm && dnf clean all 

ENTRYPOINT php-fpm
EXPOSE 9000
```

Build it from the same directory using `podman build Dockerfile`. Run it using `podman run`, and use the `-v` argument to share the necessary directories with the PHP running inside. Configure your nginx or Apache to connect to port 9000 for PHP support via fastcgi.